# Reference to original document kept?

Tags: indexing, solr

This is a Solr newbie question - nevertheless very important for me to understand how Solr works and if it suits me for a project.

I want to index binary documents, i.e. MS-Office documents and PDFs. I understand Solr can index the content of these documents and I can build queries to get values and fields that I specify back as a result. My question is what happens to the PDF (or any document) after it has been scanned? Is it actually stored or completely discarded and can I get a reference/link back to the original document incl. location (path) back from solr or do I have to pass this information in at the time of submitting the document?

Can someone help me to understand this please?

Answer (score 0):

You can index anything you want basically and SOLR will allow you to search it and return results.  For instance we use Nutch to index our web site AND we have home made Groovy scripts that pull data out of a database and create a SOLR index.

The important part is how you are building your indexes.  If you provide a URL or other resource locator to be able to link to your files then you can have SOLR return that information in the results payload.